# how do i set the origin to the center of the bounding box?

Tags: transforms

How can i set the origin of an object exactly into the center of it´s boundingbox?

I find no such options in the menu.

I find only mass centers and things like geometry to origin.
but that does not find the right spot.

Answer (score 6):

Change the transform pivot point to *Bounding Box Center* and set the origin to *Geometry* using the right click menu.

[image: Transform pivot point]

[image: Setting origin to geometry]

If you want to do it more precisely, Set the pivot point to *Bounding Box Center*; move the 3D cursor to the object (Shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd>–<kbd>S</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>) and use the right click menu to set *Origin to 3D Cursor*.