# I'm trying to extrude the icing on the donut but it causing the mesh to deform

Tags: modeling, modifiers

[image]

[image]

I'm an absolute beginner at this point (only my second day). As you can see in the images, I tried to extrude the icing along one side but it caused the icing mesh to deform badly on the opposite side, almost as if someone ate the mesh. Can someone please explain what might be causing this? I tried deleting icings multiple times and remaking it but every this deformation shows up :(

Comment: Try switching on x-ray view by alt+z and see whether or not the vertices on the opposite side are selected when you select the ones on this side.

Comment: Thanks for your response :) I tried it now and no vertices were selected on the opposite side.

Comment: Can you precise what is "extrude along one side"? Did you use Scale? Scale along normals? Grab? Sculpt?
Was it in Edit mode?
I also can see that you are transforming things from their individual origin. This might be the issue. Check here:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/260528/how-do-i-set-the-origin-to-the-center-of-the-bounding-box

Comment: @Bruh You should at least show us some screenshots of your mesh in Edit Mode. It would even be better if you could share snapshots (preferably GIF) of you trying to do the extrusion so that we can fidure out what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Also you need to check that only the vertices you want are selected before you extrude.